# Who are the characters on the Daily Bugle’s front page in "X-Men '97" Episode 1?

Tags: marvel, x-men, character-identification, x-men-97

In *X-Men '97* Season 1, Episode 1, a quick shot of a Daily Bugle front page appears prominently after Cyclops blasts villains in a warehouse. The headline reads "Benetton's Mutant Fashion Show" and features characters who seem to be nods to existing mutant characters.

[image: Daily Bugle front page]

(This isn't the only mutant tease in the episode, as I noticed a reference to Fabio Medina (Goldballs), who did not appear in the episode. And interestingly, the [same Daily Bugle front page throws in familiar names like Spider-Man, Peter Parker, and Eddie Brock (Venom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz0PF.jpg).)

**Do the figures represent known mutants or other Marvel characters? If they do, which characters are they?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From left to right:

- **[Loa (Alani Ryan)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Alani_Ryan_(Earth-616))**

> [image: Image of Loa (Alani Ryan) from "X-Men Vol. 5 #11."]
>
> <sub>*[X-Men Vol. 5 #11](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men_Vol_5_11)* (October, 2020)</sub>

- **[Nature Girl (Lin Li)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Lin_Li_(Earth-616))**

> [image: Image of Nature Girl (Lin Li) from "X-Men Unlimited Infinity Comic Vol. 1 #5."]
>
> <sub>*[X-Men Unlimited Infinity Comic Vol. 1 #5](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men_Unlimited_Infinity_Comic_Vol_1_5)* (September, 2021)</sub>

- **[Stacy X (Miranda Leevald)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Miranda_Leevald_(Earth-616))**

> [image: Image of Stacy X (Miranda Leevald) from "Uncanny X-Men Vol. 1 #406."]
>
> <sub>*[Uncanny X-Men Vol. 1 #406](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_406)* (July, 2002)</sub>

- **[Banshee (Sean Cassidy)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sean_Cassidy_(Earth-616))**

> [image: Image of Banshee (Sean Cassidy) from "Legion of X Vol. 1 #2."]
>
> <sub>*[Legion of X Vol. 1 #2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Legion_of_X_Vol_1_2)* (August, 2022)</sub>

- **[Maggott (Japheth)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Maggott_(Japheth)_(Earth-616))**

> [image: Image of Maggott (Japheth) from "Generation X Vol. 1 #48."]
>
> <sub>*[Generation X Vol. 1 #48](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Generation_X_Vol_1_48)* (February, 1999)</sub>

- **[Dust (Sooraya Qadir)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sooraya_Qadir_(Earth-616))**

> [image: Image of Dust (Sooraya Qadir) from "New X-Men: Hellions Vol. 1 #2."]
>
> <sub>*[New X-Men: Hellions Vol. 1 #2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/New_X-Men:_Hellions_Vol_1_2)* (August, 2005)</sub>